# Point shapefile shows in map but not in print composer or on export

Tags: qgis, print-composer, svg

I have a point shapefile in QGIS 2.18.  I can see the points on the map but they do not appear in the print composer.  The points do not show on export to pdf.  I do have other points that display just fine and no point files have scale dependent display settings.  The points in question are symbolized with categorized SVGs.  Why will my points not show?  Note, the shapefile that is visible was created in ArcGIS and the points that are not visible were created in QGIS.

Comment: Did you define the correct projection when you created the point shapefile in QGIS?

Comment: Give us a screenshot

Comment: Yes on the correct projections.  All data and the map reference UTM10NNAD83.  I can't give you a screen shot because I deleted the offending map in the print composer.  After creating a new map, the points displayed just fine.  The original map was created in a later (Non LTR) release of QGIS.  I rolled back to 2.18, the map opened but apparently some bits were lost.  Thanks for replying, problem solved.